# How to open closed eyelids on pre made models

Tags: rigging, bones, edit-mode, shape-keys, rigify

I'm "kind of" new to Blender and rigging/animation in general, but I like to jump out in the deep part of the pool. (Sorry)

What I mainly want to do is rigging and animation, so I've kind of not paid too much attention to modeling specifics. To this end, I decided to start with rigging a World of Warcraft Blood Elf Female model. (They seemed more proportionally correct than humans)

I've been using Blender 2.79 with the Rigify addon. (Which includes the face) The armature is assigned with automatic weights. This works good on most parts except for the  face. Now, when I try to go in and manually weight the face, I'm running into issues with the eye lids and the standard bones that was included in the meta-rig.

The character has it's own verticies for the eyelids and they start out closed.

[image: Blood elf eyelids with verts]

Behind that, you find this, which simulates an eye socket when the eye is open (The eye itself is hidden):

[image: Behind eye]

Now, I can get my hands on a version with the eyes open, but that one is already posed, so I'm struggling with getting any kind of shape key to work.

[image]

Now, my struggle is how to open the eyelids using something that does not necessarily involve manually editing the verts of the eyes on the non posed model. I find that Blender has a lot of features I yet have to discover. Any tips for opening/rigging the eyelids?

PS: The model itself is accessible through exporting from WoW Model Viewer.(Need to have WoW installed)

Comment: People often use Shape Keys to control the opening of the eyes. Then they add Drivers to control those Shape Keys with Bones

Comment: @HenrikD How do you do this?

Comment: @AaronFranke There are good tutorials on youtube on this topic